# extract information from csv by using python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to extract how many songs are release in every year from csv. my data looks like this

```
no,artist,name,year
"1","Bing Crosby","White Christmas","1942"
"2","Bill Haley & his Comets","Rock Around the Clock","1955"
"3","Sinead O'Connor","Nothing Compares 2 U","1990","35.554"
"4","Celine Dion","My Heart Will Go On","1998","35.405"
"5","Bryan Adams","(Everything I Do) I Do it For You","1991"
"6","The Beatles","Hey Jude","1968"
"7","Whitney Houston","I Will Always Love You","1992","34.560"
"8","Pink Floyd","Another Brick in the Wall (part 2)","1980"
"9","Irene Cara","Flashdance... What a Feeling","1983"
"10","Elton John","Candle in the Wind '97","1992"
```

my files consists of 3000 lines data with additional fields but i am interested to extract how many songs are released in every year

i tried to extract the year and songs and my code is here, but I am new in python and therefore I don't know how to solve my problem. my code is

```
from itertools import islice
import csv


filename = '/home/rob/traintask/top3000songs.csv'
data = csv.reader(open(filename))
# Read the column names from the first line of the file
fields = data.next()[3]  // I tried to read the year columns
print fields
count = 0
for row in data:
    # Zip together the field names and values
    items = zip(fields, row)
    item = {}   \\ here I am lost, i think i should make a dict and set year as key and no of songs as values, but I don't know how to do it
    # Add the value to our dictionary
    for (name, value) in items:
        item[name] = value.strip()
        print 'item: ', item
```

I am doing it completely wrong. but If somebody give me some hints or help that how i can count no of songs released in a year. i will be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 very simple lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
my_csv=pd.read_csv(filename)
```

and to get the number of songs per year:

```
songs_per_year= my_csv.groupby('year')['name'].count()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but how i can calculate that how many songs are released for every year. I know I had to make a loop but I don't have any logic for that.  and second it is possible to use simple csv and not pandas?

Comment: my_csv.groupby('year')['names'].count()

Comment: @rob BTW your CSV is problematic since some rows has 5 fields and not 4.

Comment: songs_per_year = my_csv.groupby('year').size() is cleaner, I think.

Comment: @beniev I will accept your answer cause your and timgeb both answer works fine for me, but you respond first.

Comment: @andre I partially agree, even though in my POV it is a bit less readable since it is less clear we are counting the songs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Counter` object from the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module..

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from csv import reader
>>> 
>>> YEAR = 3
>>> with open('file.txt') as f:
...     next(f, None) # discard header
...     year2rel = Counter(int(line[YEAR]) for line in reader(f))
... 
>>> year2rel
Counter({1992: 2, 1942: 2, 1955: 1, 1990: 1, 1991: 1, 1968: 1, 1980: 1, 1983: 1})
```

Comment: thanx a lot. I will give it a try and will come back soon.

Comment: @thanks a lot timgeb. your solution also works fine and also beniev. I will accept his answer because if repled first. but I am really thankful to you for your help.